# A question on trigonometry with triangles.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, geometric-inequalities

Given that $a>b$. If $a+Ha\leq b+Hb$, find $c$, where $a,b,c$ are the sides $BC,AC,AB$ of triangle $ABC$ and $Ha$,$Hb$ are altitudes through $A$ and $B$ respectively.

I tried something and got that $2R \leq c$, where $R$ is circumradius. I don't know if it's correct, and if even it is....it's not sufficient.
Please help me with this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the given inequality we get by using $$h_a=\frac{2S}{a},h_b=\frac{2S}{b}$$
$$a-b\le 2S\left(\frac{a-b}{ab}\right)$$ or $$ab\le 2S$$  with $$S=\frac{1}{2}ab\sin(\gamma)$$ we get $$1\le \sin(\gamma)$$
can you finish?

Comment: So what's the answer? And how exactly can I take it from here. Is it Like since sin C cannot be greater than 1, so sinC=1?

Comment: yes this is exactly the result

Comment: So c=2R which implies angle C is 90 degrees?

Comment: this is also true

Comment: ok thanks....well that's what I got before posting the question. Thanks for the help ^.^

Comment: do you want to testing me? ok, that is nice! have a nice day!

Comment: c'mon I wasnt testing you....I just wasn't confident enough of my answer

Comment: this was only a joke